# How to convert ASCII characters to string in Android?

Tags: java, android, string, ascii

I am loading a text to TextView but the problem is that the text is full of ASCII characters, so when the text is loaded to the TextView, I can't see anything or it shows me completly other character. For example instead of character "ó" a "?" within a black square is shown.

My question is, how can I convert an ASCII character to string?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Please post the code for loading the text.

Comment: text encoding may be?

Comment: You should read about and understand what ASCII, Unicode, encoding and strings are before trying to solve your problem.  The example you've given is not ASCII.

Comment: Short answer: use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[], java.nio.charset.Charset) with the "right" Charset.  "windows-1252" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) is currently supported on Android; give that a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

€ is not an Ascii character. Instead you probably are using Windows-1252 encoding on your source files, or similar. There the € is mapped to a character 128, which in Unicode is a control character.

Edit: as it is apparent, that the text is loaded from the internet, and nonmodifiable, and whatnot, then the following code could work:

```
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(
        yourInputStream, "windows-1252"); 
        // or what ever seems to be the correct encoding!

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

while (reader.ready())
{
    builder.append(reader.read());
}
reader.close();

String string = builder.toString();
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, you are right. But there are some other characters(ó, BEL-this is shown in Notepad++) which are ASCII character, and it shows me the same

Comment: no, ó is not an ASCII character. Save your files in UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: But I have seen it on this webpage under the Extended ASCII codes title: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: You are right, however extended ASCII is *no* standard, standard US-ASCII is 7 bits, extended ASCII has an 8th bit set, and a multitude of OS/platform/language encodings exist for "extended" ASCII. "Windows-1252" (Windows Latin-1) is a good bet. The shown "ISO-8859-1" (Latin-1) is a very US centric/historical view.

Comment: And what are you suggesting to do? That file is given, I don't think I can change something on it, because my app loads it from a webpage. Is there some kind of code which is able to convert the loaded text to readable form?

Comment: Then why don't you ASK so